# After sign_in/up redirection trouble with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want after login user redirects to page creating new table(website), so I have function in my ApplicationController:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 new_website_path 
end
```

and after registration I want user redirects to his edit page:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 edit_user_registration_path
end
```

So the question is - why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` is a protected method of the Devise registrations controller as you can see [in the controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). The only way you will be able to get a custom redirect after sign up, is to override the Devise registrations controller on your own. There are instructions on doing so on the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29).

Comment: Thank u for help.
I have some troubles again.
You can see my code below.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed access level like this:

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 protected
   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path
   end
 protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    new_website_path
   end
  end
```

Before this at it was working for after_sign_in and after_sign_out and now it doesn't wor at all. Why ?

Comment: `after_sign_in_path` needs to stay in your application controller, as it will not be called from the registrations controller. As for your registrations controller, you have to follow the second step in the wiki article I linked you to and tell Devise to use your controller instead of theirs. If you follow both steps in that link it will work.